# PCA as Pre-Processing before Clustering through GMM

Tags: clustering, pca, multivariate-analysis, gaussian-mixture-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose I start with a data matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times D}$, where each row $x_i$ is $D$-dimensional  sample. I would like to cluster this data through a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM).

If I pre-process the data using PCA, then I can attain a new data matrix $X' \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times D}$, where each variable (column) are orthogonal to each other. I think this implies that the covariance matrix of this transformed data is diagonal.

My questions are

- Would it make sense to assume that the components in my GMM have diagonal covariance matrices?
- Is there any relationship between this process and Probabilistic PCA (PPCA)?
- Does this process make sense / when would I want to use PCA before clustering in GMM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Would it make sense to assume that the components in my GMM have diagonal covariance matrices?**

No.
Define a $K=2$ mixture of bi-variate Gaussian distributions with covariance matrices that are not diagonal:

$$
f(X)=\sum_{k=1}^K\pi_k\mathcal{N}_k(\mathbf{0},\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_k)
$$ where: $\pi_1=\pi_2=0.5$
$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
2,1\\
1,2                       
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
2,-1\\
-1,2                       
\end{pmatrix}
$$
My intuition tells me that the overall covariance matrix $Var(X)$ would be diagonal.

**2. Is there any relationship between this process and Probabilistic PCA (PPCA)?**

Sort of. PPCA is a PCA equivalent using MLE instead of SVD for solution. In this way, PPCA is related to your process.

**3. Does this process make sense / when would I want to use PCA before clustering in GMM?**

It makes sense since conventional GMM can not handle high dimensional data. But we have better ways of doing it. You can check Mixture of Probabilistic PCA:

http://www.miketipping.com/papers/met-mppca.pdf